# How to read data from a nested select query linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I have a query like the following which is of type linq.

```
var querymiangin = (from t1 in _context.Apiapplicant
                    join t2 in _context.ApiApplicantHistory on t1.Id equals t2.ApiApplicantId
                    join t3 in _context.EntityType on t2.LastReqStatus equals t3.Id
                    where t1.IsDeleted == false && t1.LastRequestStatus == t2.Id && t3.Name == "granted"
                    select new { A = t1, B = t2, Year = t1.ApiRequestDate.Substring(0, 4), Month = t1.ApiRequestDate.Substring(5, 2) } into joined
                    group joined by new { joined.Year, joined.Month, joined.B.LastReqStatus } into grouped
                    select grouped.Select(g => new { ApiReqDate = g.A.ApiRequestDate, ApiDate = g.B.Date, ApiLastReqStatus = g.B.LastReqStatus, ApiYear = g.Year, ApiMonth = g.Month })).ToList();
```

In the select part, ApiReqDate and ApiDate has multiple records. Now my problem is for each group of month and year, I have multiple ApiDate and ApiReqDate records and I want for each group based on a condition (t1.LastRequestStatus == t2.Id && t3.Name == "granted") by using GetPersianDaysDiffDate() method, obtain the difference between ApiReqDate and its related ApiDate records for each month and then find their average in that month.

For doing that, I have written code like this:

```
var avgDateDiff = querymiangin.DefaultIfEmpty()
       .GroupBy(x => new { x.ApiYear, x.ApiMonth }, (key, g) => new
       {
           key.ApiYear,
           key.ApiYear,
           Avg = g.Average(y => GetPersianDaysDiffDate(y.ApiReqDate,y.ApiDate))
       })
       .ToList();
```

But the problem is each parameter x.ApiYear, x.ApiMonth,y.ApiReqDate,y.ApiDate are unknown and it shows me error. I appreciate if anyone can suggest me a solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - For the first request `querymiangin`, you don't need to `group by` statement, change little the code to :

```
var querymiangin = (from t1 in Apiapplicant
                    join t2 in ApiApplicantHistory on t1.Id equals t2.ApiApplicantId
                    join t3 in EntityType on t2.LastReqStatus equals t3.Id
                    where t1.IsDeleted == false && t1.LastRequestStatus == t2.Id && t3.Name == "granted"
                    select new
                    {
                        ApiReqDate = t1.ApiRequestDate,
                        ApiDate = t2.Date,
                        ApiYear = t1.ApiRequestDate.Substring(0, 4),
                        ApiMonth = t1.ApiRequestDate.Substring(5, 2)
                    }).ToList();
```

2 - For the second query `avgDateDiff`, use `GroupBy` by `ApiYear` and `ApiMonth` and calculate the `Average`, like :

```
var avgDateDiff = querymiangin
       .GroupBy(x => new { x.ApiYear, x.ApiMonth }, (key, g) => new
       {
           key.ApiYear,
           key.ApiMonth,
           Avg = g.Average(y => GetPersianDaysDiffDate(y.ApiReqDate, y.ApiDate))
       }).ToList();
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I edited my code like what you mentioned however the problem still exists and the parameters are unknown.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. for your first query suggestion, there is an error like the following: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression 'x => x' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.

Comment: And for your second suggestion, there is an error like the following: InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: new { Year = (SUBSTRING((a.apiRequestDate), ((0) + (1)), (4))), Month = (SUBSTRING((a.apiRequestDate), ((5) + (1)), (2))), LastReqStatus = (a.lastReqStatus) }, ElementSelector:new { A = (EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: Apiapplicant ValueBufferExpression: (ProjectionBindingExpression: A) ....

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What should I try?

Comment: There is an error for SelectMany part: The type arguments with the method IEnumerable.SelectMany can not be inferred from the usage.

Comment: If I use querymiangin like what you wrote and for avgDateDiff, use var avgDateDiff = querymiangin.GroupBy(x => new { x.ApiYear, x.ApiMonth }).Select(x => new { x.Key.ApiYear, x.Key.ApiMonth, Avg = x.Average(y => GetPersianDaysDiffDate(y.ApiReqDate, y.ApiDate)) }).ToList(); there is an error like: InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector... . The error is for querymiangin part.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now there isn't any data result for both queries which you updated. for testing them, I wrote foreach (var t in querymiangin){Console.WriteLine("t.ApiDate1:" + t.ApiDate); and  foreach (var t in avgDateDiff) {Console.WriteLine("t.ApiMonth:" + t.ApiMonth); //+ "+" + t. + "+" + t.Year);}} and both of these foreach loop doesn't show me any data

Comment: @MinaMRM use just `Console.WriteLine(querymiangin.Count);` for the first and `Console.WriteLine(avgDateDiff.Count);` for the second.

Comment: querymiangin.Count returns 0

Comment: @MinaMRM can you share your request sql that do the something, I doubt the tables are empty or the where not satisfied

Comment: @MinaMRM not the same, the query above select just from `Apiapplicant`, but the the request in my response take from 3 tables `Apiapplicant`, `ApiApplicantHistory ` and `EntityType`. check data in all tables.